# How to get search results in SharePoint (Office 365 E3)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have a problem with documents and pages search feature. Here's what I've done:

1. Created a trial account of Office 365 E3 based on default `.onmicrosoft.com` domain name:

> Office 365 E3
>  Microsoft Kaizala Pro
>  Whiteboard (Plan 2)
>   Information Protection for Office 365 - Standard
>  Insights by
>   MyAnalytics
>  To-Do (Plan 2)
>  Microsoft Forms (Plan E3)
>   Microsoft Stream for O365 E3 SKU
>  Microsoft StaffHub
>  Flow for
>   Office 365
>  PowerApps for Office 365
>  Microsoft Teams
>   Microsoft Planner
>  Sway
>  Yammer Enterprise
>  Azure Rights
>   Management
>  The latest desktop version of Office
>  Skype for
>   Business Online (Plan 2)
>  Office for the web
>  SharePoint Online
>   (Plan 2)
>  Exchange Online (Plan 2)

2. Created a communication site and added a couple of word documents, links, web pages.
3. Configured the site as follow:

   ```
   Settings
    Site Information
     View all site settings
      Search and Offline Availability
       Allow this site to appear in search results? -> **Yes**
       This site contains fine-grained permissions. Specify the site's ASPX page indexing behavior: -> **Always index all Web Parts on this site**

       Reindex site
   ```

   ```
   Documents
    Library Settings
     Advanced Settings
      Allow items from this document library to appear in search results? -> **Yes**
      Allow non-default views from this list to appear in search results? -> **Yes**

      Reindex Document Library
   ```
4. Performed search on the main site's page and on the Documents page with a result:
   `We found 0 results for document here` or `No items match your search`
5. I spent a lot of time googling and did not finding a solution. I've also read questions and answers on this resource, but have not find solution that could help.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work along 5 hours I was playing with it. But when I've finished playing with it, went to bed and returned to it again 11 hours later it turned out working. I don't understand why `Reindex Site` and `Reindex Document Library` buttons did not help to reindex site's and library's contents in a half an hour at least, but took so much time. 
I've been configuring also

```
 SharePoint admin center
  Search
   Authoritative pages
   Search Center Settings
```

```
 SharePoint
  Site Settings
   Site Features
    SharePoint Server Standard Site features -> Active
   Regional Settings
    Time Zone -> UTC+02:00
```

But unsure it helped. Maybe crawl schedule plays the role.